# Transition on div height change caused by its inner element showing or hiding

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a wrapper div which has 2 inner div's  , the 2nd inner div has a toggle of show/hide  , since it's an inner element , its appearance/disappearance cause to height change on the wrapper .

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to animate this change by `transition: height` property  .

In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58qxffbr/3/) I tried to animate the wrapper height change with no success .

How to get that ?

Note :

1) I don't know the actually `height` after each show/hide .

2) I looking for a pure css solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you perfectly, You should use `transition: height` on `.blue`

```
.blue {
        background-color : blue ; 
        width : 500px ; 
        height : 0px ; 
        -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
        transition: height 2s;
    }
    .blue.show {
        height:300px;
    }
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/58qxffbr/4/)